# Why can't closed subschemes be defined in an easier way?

Tags: soft-question, schemes

My (naive) definition of closed subscheme of a scheme $X$ would be: a closed subset $Z \overset{j}{\hookrightarrow} X$ endowed with the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_Z := j^{-1}\mathcal{O}_X$. Apparently, though, this is too narrow a definition, and we need to allow for structure sheaves of the form $j^{-1} \left( \mathcal{O}_X / \mathcal{I} \right)$, where $\mathcal{I} \subseteq \mathcal{O}_X$ is a sheaf of ideals. Can anybody explain to me why this is needed?

Comment: Actually, maybe I have an idea of a possible explanation: this definition would allow only one scheme structure on each closed subset. But with the generalization, one could for instance put a (unique) reduced scheme structure on each scheme and consider it as a closed subscheme (even if the underlying topological space is the same)

Comment: Your comment really answers the question : we are interested in more than one scheme structure on a closed subset. For example, the intersection of the parabola $y=x^2$ and the line $y=0$ is just a point, but a non reduced one because the line is tangent to the parabola, in other words they intersect with multiplicity.